# which datatype is used for inserting the data from 10,000 to 100,000 in a column other than varchar

Tags: mysql, oracle

I want to insert the data in a table from 10,000 to 100,000 size in a column.which datatype I should use other than varchar.

Comment: You can use the `clob`

Comment: This look like [a good place to start researching the answer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html)

Comment: I think OP asked to insert the string of 10,000 to 100,000 characters, If I am not wrong!!

Comment: @Tejash Yea, the penny just dropped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **CLOB** to store such a big string. If it is characters.

You can see it from oracle documentation:

> CLOB: Maximum size: (4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter (8 TB to 128 TB)

For all the data types and their limits, refer to this [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/datatype-limits.html#GUID-963C79C9-9303-49FE-8F2D-C8AAF04D3095).

Comment: In oracle - do you know of a suitable mysql datatype?

Comment: No, I haven't used MySql

Comment: According to dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html , TEXT and BLOB can hold the same amount of data (which is 64K). Use LONGTEXT and LONGBLOB to hold up to 4GB of data.